# How to restore the root page for a tab?

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic3

I'm new to Ionic 3, and what I want to do it's to get the specified scenario:

I go to Tab 1, click on some Item in Tab 1 and go to a view of this item, If I now switch to Tab 2, when I go to Tab 1, the view showed should be the Tab 1 view, not the Item View for a Tab 1 element.

In ionic 1 I previously have used `$ionicHistory.clearHistory()` but seems now it's not available. I've tried several uses of `NavController` but seems I am not using it properly or where it means to be used. How can I accomplish this scenario? Also I want to disable the `back button` in the root Tab 1 view, like, I don't want to see any type of back button when I'm on this view, without any exception.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using `popToRoot()` check this out https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot

Answer (score 0):

if any content of some tab link to  a new page . the tab should be in hidden state so add this attribute "tabsHideOnSubPages" to your tab tag.
example:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [tabsHideOnSubPages]="true" [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

So in this case when the first tab has button link to another page the state of toolbar tabs will be in hidden state and thats will not happen for second and third tab because the value of  "tabsHideOnSubPages" attribute is false by default.

Comment: i thing this will hide the tabs it self